# Add column to pandas pivot table based on complex condition

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

my pivot table looks like this:

```
In [285]: piv
Out[285]: 
K              118.5     119.0     119.5     120.0     120.5
Expiry                                                      
2018-01-12  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842
2018-01-19  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526
2018-01-26  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196
2018-02-02  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991
2018-02-23  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005
2018-03-23  0.041025  0.041000  0.040872  0.040623  0.040398
```

and df2 looks like this:

```
In [290]: df2
Out[290]: 
                              F       Symbol
Expiry                                      
2018-03-20 12:00:00  123.000000  ZN   MAR 18
2018-06-20 12:00:00  122.609375  ZN   JUN 18
```

I am looking to add piv['F'] based on the following:
piv.index.month < df2.index.month

so the result should looks like this:

```
K          F              118.5     119.0     119.5     120.0     120.5
Expiry                                                      
2018-01-19 123.000000  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526
2018-01-26 123.000000  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196
2018-02-02 123.000000  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991
2018-02-23 123.000000  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005
2018-03-23 123.609375  0.041025  0.041000  0.040872  0.040623  0.040398
```

would help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reindex` + `backfill`

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1.index=pd.to_datetime(df1.index)

df['F']=df1.reindex(df.index,method='backfill').F.values
df
Out[164]: 
               118.5     119.0     119.5     120.0     120.5           F
2018-01-12  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  123.000000
2018-01-19  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  123.000000
2018-01-26  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  123.000000
2018-02-02  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  123.000000
2018-02-23  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  123.000000
2018-03-23  0.041025  0.041000  0.040872  0.040623  0.040398  122.609375
```

Comment: Hi Wen. Thanks so much for this works great but unfortunately I had to change the script. Hence one more question. What if df1 is a df where Expiry is not the index?

Comment: @steff you can use set_index :-)

Comment: Yes know that but cannot do that as this will be a relatively big df and the expiry dates are not unique. will do it another way. Anyway thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [**`pd.merge_asof`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='forward'` and make sure to merge on the indices.

```
pd.merge_asof(
    piv, df2[['F']],
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    direction='forward'
)

               118.5     119.0     119.5     120.0     120.5           F
Expiry                                                                  
2018-01-12  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  123.000000
2018-01-19  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  123.000000
2018-01-26  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  123.000000
2018-02-02  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  123.000000
2018-02-23  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  123.000000
2018-03-23  0.041025  0.041000  0.040872  0.040623  0.040398  122.609375
```

---

And if you want `'F'` in front:

```
pd.merge_asof(
    piv, df2[['F']],
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    direction='forward'
).pipe(lambda d: d[['F']].join(d.drop('F', 1)))

                     F     118.5     119.0     119.5     120.0     120.5
Expiry                                                                  
2018-01-12  123.000000  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842  0.050842
2018-01-19  123.000000  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526  0.039526
2018-01-26  123.000000  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196  0.039196
2018-02-02  123.000000  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991  0.039991
2018-02-23  123.000000  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005  0.040005
2018-03-23  122.609375  0.041025  0.041000  0.040872  0.040623  0.040398
```